# Show data from Mysql Database using ORDER BY from One Column

Tags: php, mysql

In my Mysql Database I've one Column called `notesUpdate` where I inserting many data with date ,username and notes. So that `notesUpdate` Column hold following data.

```
2014-07-23 04:01 AM alex : First Note{ASUSIBBIR}
2014-07-23 04:01 AM alex : Second Note{ASUSIBBIR}
2014-07-23 04:02 AM alex : Third Note{ASUSIBBIR}
2014-07-23 04:02 AM alex : Fourth Note{ASUSIBBIR}
```

**Note:** {ASUSIBBIR} is a separator I'm using.

Now I'm trying to fetch these data in Descending Order. I mean Last inserted data should be at First. So I'm using following query. I know it's not right but can't get any idea how can show these data by Descending Order ?

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT notesUpdate FROM contact_details WHERE cdid = '$id' ORDER BY 
notesUpdate DESC");
```

**Data Show Should Be Look Like This:**

```
2014-07-23 04:02 AM alex : Fourth Note
2014-07-23 04:02 AM alex : Third Note
2014-07-23 04:01 AM alex : Second Note
2014-07-23 04:01 AM alex : First Note
```

**How I inserting Data to DB**

```
$username = $_SESSION['front_username'];
$contetn =  $date;
$contetn .=  " ";
$contetn .=  "$username";
$contetn .=  " : ";
$contetn .=  mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['contentText'])));
$cdid = $_POST['cdid'];
$contetn .= "{ASUSIBBIR}";  // this is a separator
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE contact_details SET notesUpdate = CONCAT(notesUpdate, 
'$contetn') WHERE cdid = '$cdid' LIMIT 1")
```

Any help ?

**Update:**

**This is the form where I insert data to db:**

```
<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
    <td><h2>Write your Notes</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="cdid" id="cdid"/>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea name="contentText" id="contentText"  cols="53" rows="5"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" class="submit" id="addNewNotes"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**This is Jquery part:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#addNewNotes', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

        var cid=$(this).parents('form:first').find('#cdid').val();
        $("#loading-image").show();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'response.php',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function(data){                                               
              getDetails(cid);
              $("#loading-image").hide(); //hide loading
              $("#Notesboxsuccess").html(data).show();        
            },

        //  complete: function(){
         // $("#loading-image").hide(); //hide loading here
        //},

            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
});

});
```

Comment: What are you getting when you run the query?

Comment: You should store the timestamp in a separate column with the data type `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`. Then you can ORDER BY this column. Because you omissed your seconds, you can't order "Fourth" before "Third" easily. This is a common princip in connection with databases: store atomic data. Your column stores at least two different informations and now you've got a problem with this.

Comment: @VMai Yes you right. But Is there no way to get this ?

Comment: @VMai I use this because I've to insert many data to One column.

Comment: If you had `2014-07-23 04:01:05 AM alex: First Note` and then `2014-07-24 04:01:12 AM alex: Second Note` then you could use by taking the DATETIME part with AM, convert this substring to a DATETIME value and order by that. But that would be inefficient, because MySQL can't use an index. Please follow my recommendation and use another column.

Comment: It's no great problem to have multiple columns. You can ever easily concatenate information from those, but it's very difficult and inefficient to parse a great mass of information only to get a certain part. If you need this part, then it will be almost best to have a separate column for that.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest select notesUpdate and split it to an array, then reverse it and dispay :) But you should consider use some relative table in databese to store changes history.

```
$result =  mysql_query("SELECT notesUpdate FROM contact_details WHERE cdid = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$notesUpdateArray = explode('{ASUSIBBIR}', $row['notesUpdate']);
$notesUpdateReversedArray = array_reverse($notesUpdateArray);


var_dump($notesUpdateReversedArray);
```

If you wont it as string just implod it back

```
$notesUpdateReversed = implode('{ASUSIBBIR}', $notesUpdateReversedArray);
```

Comment: So I've to echo this variable `$notesUpdateReversedArray` ?

Comment: @Shibbir $notesUpdateReversedArray is an array so if you want use echo you need go thru all elements, or just use: echo $notesUpdateReversed, which is already string

Comment: Now I use this variable `$notesUpdateReversed` and it's showing `{ASUSIBBIR}2014-07-23 04:02 AM alex : Fourth Note{ASUSIBBIR}2014-07-23 04:02 AM alex : Third Note{ASUSIBBIR}2014-07-23 04:01 AM alex : Second Note{ASUSIBBIR}2014-07-23 04:01 AM alex : First Note`

Comment: so change glue in implode from '{ASUSIBBIR}' to "\n" or '<br>'

Comment: Now I'm using `$test =  str_replace("{ASUSIBBIR}", "\r\n", "$notesUpdateReversed");` and It's look like working!

Comment: as I wrote its better to change glue rather then using str_replace, it will be more efective, so it should look like this `$notesUpdateReversed = implode("\r\n", $notesUpdateReversedArray);`

Comment: Yes your one is Working fine. Just AWESOME, SIMPLE AND GREAT SOLUTION! THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast the first 19 characters as a datetime object like so

```
CAST(LEFT(notesUpdate, 19) as datetime)
```

so something like

```
SELECT 
    notesUpdate 
FROM contact_details 
ORDER BY 
    STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(notesUpdate, 19), '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p') DESC, 
    id DESC
```

**NOTE:** this is NOT a recommended way to store data.. you should consider changing it.. this doesn't follow the standards of normalization.

SEE [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b44b71/2)

Comment: There's the problem that there are no seconds and so (First, Second) and (Third, Fourth) may be sorted wrong. That's not your fault :-)

Comment: @John Ruddell Let me try it.

Comment: @VMai I noticed that already because I just tried testing it.. so I added a sort on id DESC assuming there is an ID field.. that fixes it on my side :)

Comment: You've got to use 19, btw and better use STR_TO_DATE. There's the AM, PM problem too.

Comment: @Shibbir don't forget to add the WHERE back in, and also order by the ID if you have one

Comment: @JohnRuddell It's showing same result. I'm using this query `$query =  mysql_query("SELECT notesUpdate FROM contact_details WHERE cdid = '$id' ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(notesUpdate, 16) as datetime) DESC, cdid DESC");
`

Comment: @Shibbir i just updated with one change that will fix the hours.. can you post what cdid is?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I'm updating my question now.

Comment: @Shibbir i just added a sqlfiddle demo.. click the link to see what i see

Comment: @JohnRuddell You Demo link is working fine. But In my side it's not showing DESC order and I updated my question.

Comment: @Shibbir that doesn't help me.. I was asking for the data... so like you have that string that is the notesUpdate... what other data do you have... not the code but the data... do you have an ID for each row? do you have any other columns in the table?

Comment: yes I've the ID for each row. Please see this link http://www.gatecrasher.info/acc1/login.php. (Alex and 123456789)

Comment: @Shibbir ok so you have an ID.. so how is it not sorting it properly? can you replicate the data so it looks like what I did for the sqlfiddle? aka id 1 for first update, id 2 for second update.. etc?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks for helping but I fixed it from marcino0o answer. Thank You.